# How to arrange documents in Firestore using Flutter through custom document IDs?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to order the documents in Firestore. The default Firestore documents list consist of alphabetic characters which get created automatically. But I don't want that. I just want to see my newly added document added at the top of my documents list. How do I do that in flutter? It would be very helpful if you provide me with a code for that. The code I use to create a collection is:

```
Future<void> userSetup() async {
    String user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.displayName as String;
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(user);
    final hours = time?.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final minutes = time?.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    users.add({
      "customerId": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid.toString(),
      "customerName": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.displayName,
      "customerEmail": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email,
      "selectedTime": '${hours}:${minutes}',
      "selectedDate": DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(date!),
    });
    return;
  }
```

But I am unable to set my own document id. Please help me with the issue. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From the Flutterfire [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#adding-documents), the `set()` method is the one you should be using to be able to specify your own document IDs instead of `add()`. Keep in mind that if the document ID you specify already exists in your database, the whole existing document will be replaced. This is a sample usage as found in the documentation:

```dart
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> addUser() {
  return users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .set({
      'full_name': "Mary Jane",
      'age': 18
    })
    .then((value) => print("User Added"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
}
```

It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447426/) that documents are ordered alphabetically in the Firestore console, so your custom document IDs should follow alphabetical order as you require. Not to be confused with retrieving documents from Firestore in a particular order, which is [done](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#ordering) with the `orderBy()` method.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can click on the checkmark icon to mark it as accepted. This can help future users who are having the same issue.